# $\int_0^af(s)\int_0^b g(t)\left(g(t)-g(t-s) \right)dtds\leq C \int_0^af(s) \left| \int_0^b \left(g(t)-g(t-s) \right)dt \right|ds $?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, absolute-value

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be two bounded continously differentiable functions.
Do we have the existence of a constant $C$ such that
$$\int_0^af(s)\int_0^b g(t)\left(g(t)-g(t-s) \right)dtds\leq C \int_0^af(s) \left|   \int_0^b \left(g(t)-g(t-s) \right)dt  \right|ds $$
for all $a,b\geq 0$?

I think of using  the [first mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals), by this requires the function $g(t)-g(t-s)$  to have a constant sign.

Comment: Since $g$ is continuous, then $g$ is bounded by $C$, but $C$ depends on $b$ though, so my question does $C$ have to depend on $b$?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif it's ok, I can even assume the functions are bounded, I edited the question. But the problem is $g(t)-g(t-s)$ is not nonnegative. I can also assume $f$ is nonnegative. The problem is  $g(t)-g(t-s)$.

Comment: I feel there may be a counterexample of this inequality.

Comment: Try with $f=1$ and $g=\cos{t}$