# Nonconstant function such that $\int_0^1 \left| \int_0^1 \left(g(t)-g(t-s) \right)dt \right|ds=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300751/int-0afs-int-0b-gt-leftgt-gt-s-rightdtds-leq-c-int-0afs-left) question.

Is there a **nonconstant** continously differentiable  function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\int_0^1 \left|   \int_0^1 \left(g(t)-g(t-s) \right)dt  \right|ds=0$$
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(t) = \cos(2\pi t)$ works. 
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (g(t) - g(t-s))\ dt &= \int_0^1 (\cos(2\pi t) - \cos(2\pi (t-s)))\ dt \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\big[\sin(2\pi t) - \sin(2\pi (t-s)) \big]_0^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\sin(2\pi s)-\sin(2\pi(1-s))\right) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$